# How to bypass proxy for a domain exept when it starts with WWW

Tags: windows, networking, proxy, internet-explorer

Our company has a website that is hosted online and can be access only through proxy. However, there are many web application servers which have the same domain suffix but are internal and needs to be bypassed to access them. For example, suppose our website address is -

```
www.abc.com
```

and the internal web application servers might be

```
local.abc.com
local2.abc.com
def.abc.com
```

So, we have to manually add them all to the bypass rule. If we instead use `*.abc.com` to bypass them all, then users can't access `www.abc.com`. So, how can the bypass rule be set so that it works for all except when the domain starts with `www`.

Comment: Is this a change you are looking to make on the client machines (for example in IE Internet Settings), or on the proxy side? If it is client side, what browser? If it is server side, what proxy?

Comment: it's client side, internet explorer.

Comment: Been a long time since I've looked at IE proxy settings. Any chance that split horizon DNS is the better way to handle this?

Comment: Nope, split horizon DNS is not a viable option right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you will probably need to use a PAC file for defining client behavior. You can find some decent documentation about it at http://www.proxypacfiles.com, with [a basic example](http://www.proxypacfiles.com/proxypac/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=58&Itemid=87). The nice part about using a PAC file is that you can update the rules without having to wait for a GPO to push out changes. The downside is that IE by default will attempt a direct connection is the PAC file isn't available, IIRC.